# Infinispan 14.0.9 - RAM utilization

Tags: datagrid, infinispan, distributed-caching, redhat-datagrid

How can I check RAM usage in infinispan 14.0.9. Is it possible to monitor RAM utilization via WebUI or CLI? Where can I find resource consumption in Infinispan ?

I would like to know when the cluster resources are running low.